# PublicKey and PrivateKey constructor in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, cryptography

i want to keep the public and private keys I've generated with my application in a file so I could use the exact same keys another time.. but i realize that there isn't any constructor for PublicKey and PrivateKey object in Android.. so when I could keep them and read them, I still can't reuse them in my application..

could someone tell me how the way that it could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [getEncoded](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded%28%29) methods of PublicKey and PrivateKey return byte arrays that should be suitable for supplying to the constructors for [X509EncodedKeySpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) (for the PublicKey) and [PKCS8EncodedKeySpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html) (for the PrivateKey). These KeySpecs in turn may be used with the appropriate [KeyFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyFactory.html) to regenerate the private keys.

Comment: http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Supported+Curves+(ECDSA+and+ECGOST) -- Could you please tell me what does "size" in the page means? if it's the key size, i doubt that, bevause i have use the brainpoolp160r1 and having >60 bytes public key.. thanks b4 =)

Comment: Those are the sizes of the underlying fields used in the math. The public key for ECDSA can be represented in an uncompressed form which requires twice that number of bits, or in a compressed form which takes exactly that number of bits.